# Can't get hardware acceleration working with Intel Graphics passthrough on Debian VM

Tags: hardware, intel-graphics, proxmox, gpu-passthrough, vaapi

I have a Debian 11 (Bullseye) VM where I have attempted to passthrough the intel GPU according to posts like this https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/guide-intel-intergrated-graphic-passthrough.30451/

It seems to be doing something b/c Proxmox no longer outputs the console to the monitor. However I don't get the Debian VM's console on the monitor either. I don't really care about seeing the Debian VM monitor on the screen but I would like to get it working b/c I run Plex inside the VM and want to get the hardware accelerated transcoding working.

Is there an issue with the above forum post's method of blacklisting the GPU from Proxmox perhaps? If I run `vainfo` on Proxmox, I get a list of supported profiles so I know my CPU has the integrated graphics with quicksync ability. It's only on the VM I get an error like:

```
sudo vainfo

error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.10.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_10
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.10 (libva 2.10.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Coffee Lake - 2.4.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   :    VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

I am pretty sure I should be using the iHD driver b/c it works on Proxmox and according to [this](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/intel-media-va-driver) it should work. Also I tried installing those drivers on Proxmox and it worked.

I found [this guide](https://3os.org/infrastructure/proxmox/gpu-passthrough/igpu-passthrough-to-vm/#windows-virtual-machine-igpu-passthrough-configuration) where they have a q35 machine set but that doesn't work either.

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02)
00:10.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
```

Also here is the output from sudo dmesg | grep drm:

```
sudo dmesg | grep drm
[    2.382075] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    2.408821] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    2.408999] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    2.734710] bochs-drm 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.747759] [drm] Found bochs VGA, ID 0xb0c0.
[    2.747761] [drm] Framebuffer size 16384 kB @ 0xf0000000, mmio @ 0xfe470000.
[    2.749399] [drm] Found EDID data blob.
[    2.749607] [drm] Initialized bochs-drm 1.0.0 20130925 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    2.750866] fbcon: bochs-drmdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.894825] bochs-drm 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: bochs-drmdrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.183325] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    3.203854] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] Failed to find VBIOS tables (VBT)
[    3.203864] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] *ERROR* DC state mismatch (0x0 -> 0x2)
[    3.211384] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    3.316901] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
[    3.813395] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
[    4.021119] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm:add_taint_for_CI [i915]] CI tainted:0x9 by intel_gt_init+0xb4/0x2c0 [i915]
[    4.115560] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20200917 for 0000:00:10.0 on minor 1
[    4.807633] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    5.488674] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    6.202048] i915 0000:00:10.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
```

I have Googled many of the errors for hours and I'm at my wit's end. Some of the errors people say are harmless and I'm not really sure whether there are any problems in dmesg here. It seems people have gotten this to work but I don't know what I'm missing here.